# Node.js: Limit forks in cluster

Tags: node.js

I have a Web application and an application that runs in background, this last load much the server, so far has been working properly, but in the last version to add new features, carries a lot of load and blocks the server.

I have been trying to modify the code that runs the cluster, but always load the same number of processes.

This is my code:

```
var cluster = require('cluster'),
    limitWorkers = Math.ceil(require('os').cpus().length / 2),
    jobWorkers = [],
    webWorkers = [];

if(cluster.isMaster) {

    //let limit = 0;

    require('os').cpus().forEach(function() {

        addWebWorker();

        /*if(limit < limitWorkers) {

            limit++;

            addJobWorker();
        }*/
        if( limitWorkers > 0 ) {

            --limitWorkers;

            addJobWorker();
        }
    });

    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {

        if (jobWorkers.indexOf(worker.id) != -1) {

            console.log('job worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died. Trying to respawn...');

            removeJobWorker(worker.id);

            addJobWorker();
        }

        if (webWorkers.indexOf(worker.id) != -1) {


            console.log('http worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died. Trying to respawn...');

            removeWebWorker(worker.id);

            addWebWorker();
        }
    });

} else {

    console.log('start http server: ' + cluster.worker.id);
    require('./apps/web-http'); //initialize the http server here

    //if( process.env.job === 1 ){
    if( jobWorkers.indexOf(cluster.worker.id) != 1 ) {

        //if( limitWorkers > 0 ) { 

            //limitWorkers--;

            console.log('start job server: ' + cluster.worker.id);
            require('./apps/jobs-worker'); //initialize the job here
        //}
    }
}

function addWebWorker() {

    webWorkers.push(cluster.fork({web: 1}).id);
}

function addJobWorker() {

    jobWorkers.push(cluster.fork({job: 1}).id);
}

function removeWebWorker(id) {

    webWorkers.splice(webWorkers.indexOf(id), 1);
}

function removeJobWorker(id) {

   jobWorkers.splice(jobWorkers.indexOf(id), 1);
}
```

Any idea to run the job worker half the cores of the processor or just one? Thanks.

Comment: Please describe in words what you are trying to accomplish with your code modifications.  We need to know what the goal is.

Comment: @jfriend00 I need "job worker" to run a single process or half the cores of the processor. So far run a process by core, the same as the Web server, so I block the computer.